# Proof of radicals of ideals being equal

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am reading some Commutative Algebra notes, and have come across the following result:

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring, and let $a$ and $b$ be ideals of R. Then we have
$(a \cap b) \cdot (a \cap b) \subseteq a \cdot b \subseteq a \cap b$ and thus $r(a \cdot b) = r(a \cap b)$.
Here, $r( \bullet )$ is the radical.
My question is where we get this result from, or how it follows from the inclusions

Comment: Just prove that $I \subset J$ implies $r(I)\subset r(J)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two ideals $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ we always have

$$\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{b} \; \Rightarrow r(\mathfrak{a})\subset r(\mathfrak{b}).$$

But we also have $r(\mathfrak{a})\subset r(\mathfrak{a}^2)$, since $x\in r(\mathfrak{a})$ just means $x^n\in \mathfrak{a}$ for some $n$, and since $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal, then also $x^{2n}\in \mathfrak{a}^2$, thus giving $x\in r(\mathfrak{a}^2)$. Since $\mathfrak{a}^2 \subset \mathfrak{a}$,

$$ r(\mathfrak{a}) = r(\mathfrak{a}^2).$$

Then you can argue

$$r((\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b})\cdot (\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b})) \subset r(\mathfrak{a}\cdot \mathfrak{b}) \subset r(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}) = r((\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b})\cdot (\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b})),$$

which then must entail equality.